# How to match single line with wildcards in Find & Replace MS Word

Tags: regex, replace, ms-word

I have the following text, for which I´d like to match a single line in order to format with blue the whole lines that contains "Axy Opyy" and with yellow the lines that contains "Nmj Trui"

```
[3:57 p. m., 27/9/2021] Axy Opyy: A regular expression 
[3:58 p. m., 27/9/2021] Nmj Trui: (shortened as regex or regexp;[1] sometimes
[4:19 p. m., 27/9/2021] Nmj Trui: referred to as rational expression[2][3]) 
[5:58 p. m., 27/9/2021] Nmj Trui: is a sequence of 
[5:59 p. m., 27/9/2021] Axy Opyy: characters that specifies 
[5:59 p. m., 27/9/2021] Nmj Trui: a search pattern 
[0:13 p. m., 28/9/2021] Nmj Trui: in text.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4yRI.png)

I´ve tried different combinations with wildcard option, like `\[?@[!^13]?@\] Axy Opyy:[!^13]{1,}` or `(\[?@2021\]){1} Axy Opyy:?@^13`, but in several cases, matches more than one line. How would be the correct regex to match a single line each time? Thanks

**UPDATE**

[My currently output is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyCq.png). I´d like to shift to the right a little bit the lines that would be blue. Currently the space to the left is still highlighted. Is there a way to highlight only the text after the space?Or insert a bullet in order that the text look aligned like the image below?

[Final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq20p.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = \[[!^13]@Axy Opyy[!^13]@^13
Replace = ^&
```

and you specify the replacement colour.

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems to work pretty fine. My final goal is to get the `Final output` as in the image I explained below `UPDATE` in original post, if possible.

Comment: Instead of inserting a links to the graphic in your post, insert the graphic itself. Achieving the required output is just a matter of predefining paragraph Styles with the attributes you require and specifying those Styles as the replacement parameter.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I was able to create a custom style and it worked. Thank you. Regarding insert the image, I've pasted like it says, but not sure why is not inserted in the body of question and only shows the link.

Comment: I forgot to ask, what does mean `Replace with: ^&`? Why not just leave empty in `Replace with`?

Comment: The ^& tells Word to replace with the found content. Leave it empty and your content will be deleted...